# php get the same index values from two arrays (outside foreach)

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Have array named for example `$data_debit_turnover`

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover] => 63
        [Total] => 0.00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover] => 64
        [Total] => 44.28
    )
)
```

Have `HTML` that need to look like this

```
<table><tr>
<td><strong>63</strong></td>
<td>0.00</td>
</tr><tr>
<td><strong>64</strong></td>
<td>44.28</td>
</tr></table>
```

At first tried with php `foreach`, but in such case instead of one table get multiple tables `[0], [1]` etc.

Then tried

```
<td><strong>64</strong></td>
<td><?php
if( $data_debit_turnover[1][VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover] == '64'){
echo $data_debit_turnover[1][Total]. ' Total<br>';
}?>
</td>
```

but problem is with `[1]` etc. I do not know number of `[]`; may be `[1]` and may be `[30]`.

Tried something like this

```
$resultVatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover = array();
$resultTotal = array();
foreach($data_debit_turnover as $i => $result){
$resultVatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover[] = $result[VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover];
$resultTotal[] = $result[Total];
}

<td><strong>64</strong></td>
<td><?php
if (in_array('64', $resultVatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover)) {
echo $resultTotal[1];
}?>
</td>
```

The same problem `[1]`. How to echo corresponding (index) value from the another array.

For example if `64` is the second value in array `$resultVatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover` then need to echo the second value from array `$resultTotal`.

Possibly there is some other way.

Please advice.

Showing what I did with `foreach`

```
<?php
foreach($data_debit_turnover as $i => $result){
?>
<table>
<tr>
<td><strong>63</strong></td>
<td>
<?php if($result[VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover] = '63') {
echo $result[Total];
} ?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>64</strong></td>
<td>
<?php if($result[VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover] = '64') {
echo $result[Total];
} ?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
```

**Update** Thanks to @user2340218 advice get some solution. For each `<td>` must use `foreach`. Possibly there is some better solution.

```
<table><tr>
<td><strong>64</strong></td>
<td><?php foreach($data_debit_turnover as $vatReturn){if($vatReturn['VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover'] == '64') {echo $vatReturn['Total'];}}?></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><strong>67</strong></td>
<td><?php foreach($data_debit_turnover as $vatReturn){if($vatReturn['VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover'] == '67') {echo $vatReturn['Total'];}}?></td>
</tr></table>
```

**Solution** Finally used solution @Daniel P advised.

```
$resultVatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover = array();
$resultTotal = array();
foreach($data_debit_turnover as $i => $result){
$resultVatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover[] = $result[VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover];
$resultTotal[] = $result[Total];
}

$VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnoverModified = array_combine($resultVatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover, $resultTotal);


<table>
<tr>
<td><strong>62</strong></td>
<td>
<?php echo $VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnoverModified[62]; ?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>63</strong></td>
<td>
<?php echo $VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnoverModified[63]; ?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Actually have to accept @Daniel P answer:) But as understand can not accept 2 answers

Comment: Added `foreach` at the end. Get so many tables as have number of `array` keys. But need only one table

Comment: Then move `<table>` outside `foreach`. Isn't it obvious?

Comment: If table outside `foreach` then how can I use this code `<?php if($result[VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover] = '64') {echo $result[Total];} ?>`. Result always would be `0`!

Comment: How does php operation result and html-tag are connected?

Comment: I am guessing that `VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover` is a unique number? If that is the case you should build a array and use that number as a index. In your `if` clause you will have to use `isset()`

Comment: Seems that @user2340218 and @Zeus Alexander solution works. Simply needed `<table>` to place outside `foreach`....

Comment: The updated solution does indeed work but beware, if you array gets large and you have lots of calls this might become CPU intensive because the whole array is walked over and over. If your projects is rather small I don't see any problems with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
<table>
<?php foreach($data_debit_turnover as $vatReturn){ ?>
     <tr>
        <td><strong><?php print $vatReturn['VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover'] ?></strong></td>
        <td><?php print $vatReturn['total'] ?></td>
     </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes.... seems it works. Have not think that only `<table>` need to be outside `foreach`. I will test again.

Comment: Based on your advice get some solution (posted in question after Update). Possibly there some better solution....

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing that `VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover` numbers are unique so your array should look like this :

```
Array
(
    [63] => 0.00
    [64] => 44.28
)
```

The array index is your `VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover` and the value is your total.

To test if a `VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover` has a value your simply use `isset()`

```
if (isset($array[63])) {
    echo $array[63]
}
```

Building the table :

```
<table>
<?php foreach($data_debit_turnover as $i => $total){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><strong><?php echo $i; ?></strong></td>
        <td><?php echo $total; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: As I understand I need to convert `VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover` to `[63] [64]` etc. And then in necessary `<td>` must use `if (isset($array[63])) {echo $array[63]}`? And no `foreach`? It would be better solution. I will check. Numbers 63,64 etc. need to be written "by hand" not by script. Instead of `<?php echo $i; ?>` need to be "unchangeable" number: 63, 64, 67 etc.

Comment: The advantage of putting your data in a array this way is that you do not need to walk the whole array with `foreach()` each time you wanna look up a value. beware that `VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover` has to be unique (which I am guess is the case). You can lookup a single value with `if (isset($array[63]))` or display the whole content with `foreach()`

Comment: Will check all. I think I can get/change that `VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover` is unique. Yes, `(isset($array[]))` would be better

Answer (score 1):

Use `foreach` like this:

```
<table>
<?php
foreach ($Array as $item)
{
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td><strong>' . $item['VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover'] . '</strong></td>';
   echo '<td>' . $item['Total'] . '</td>';
   echo '</tr>'
}
?>
</table>
```